# How to color values in one column based on the hex string found in another column?

Tags: html, css, r

I have a datatable, call it **T**, as follows:

```
library(DT)
T <- data.frame(
  col1= c("abcd", "wxyz"),
  col2 =c("#ff0000","#00FF00"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My goal is have a single column where the values in col1 are colored accordingly with the hex values in col2.

I have attempted:

```
datatable(T) %>% formatStyle(
  'col1',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), list(unique(T$col2))
)
```

This reference might help https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html, I just need help with the workaround. Please let me know if I can clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want

```
datatable(T[, "col1", drop=FALSE]) %>% formatStyle(
  'col1',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(T$col1, T$col2)
  )
```

Here I drop the column you don't want to show and then use `styleEqual` to set the colors based on the values in the that column.